# Compound Interest and Oscillation

Tags: limits, exponential-function

If we calculate compound interest, it will approach continuous interest as we compound more and more frequently. However, in the region of $3.0e10^7$, compound interest exceeds continuous interest. From that point, it begins to oscillate slightly above and slightly below the value of $P*e^{rt}$. How can we say the limit exists if we have these finite oscillations?

Comment: I thought it was a strictly increasing but bounded function

Comment: Are you sure about that? It's possible you're running into numerical errors in whatever method you're using to calculate the two. Even if that's not the case, then an oscillating function can still have (a) a limit or (b) asymptotic behaviour (for example, y=(sin x)/x goes to 0 as x goes to infinity, it wouldn't take much effort to design an oscillating function that's asymptotic to e^x).

Comment: Anyway something can oscillate and converge.  Consider $\frac1x\sin x$ as $x\to\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with compound interest calculations, but about how machines work.

Although numbers can become infinitely large and require more and more precision, computer memory is *not* infinite.

(Floating-point) numbers are not represented perfectly in computers or calculators, hence you get these kinds of oscillations for very large (or very small) numbers without it actually happening if you were to do this purely algebraically using pen and paper.

Comment: Thanks, @naslundx. This is what I suspected, but I guess I needed the reassurance.